# How to retain appended values inside a div after postback? codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

My program has textboxes and a div where I append the titles of my inserted values. When I save my form, all the fields should be initialized but the div should still contain the list of titles.

here's the div:

```
    <div id = "scenario_list"></div></br>
    </div>
```

and here's how I append the titles:

```
$("#save_scenario").click(function(){
        $("#scenario_list").append('<a href="#" id ="'+testcase_id+'">'+testcase+'</a></br>');
});
```

Here's my ajax code for saving the form:

```
 $('#btnSave').click(function(){
               //$("#tc").submit();
               if(confirm("Are you sure want to save this transaction?")==false){
                 return false;
               }else{

                    $.ajax({
                        type:'post',
                        dataType:'json',
                        url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>'+'index.php/testscript/save_testscript',
                        data: {         
                                proj_name         : $('#proj_name').find("option:selected").text(),//$("select[name=proj_name]").val(),
                                hdn_catid         : $("input[name=hdn_catid]").val(),
                                hdn_testcaseid    : $("input[name=hdn_testcaseid]").val(),
                                txt_testscriptname: $("input[name=txt_testscriptname]").val(),
                                txt_testsite      : $("input[name=txt_testsite]").val(),
                                txt_testdesc      : $("input[name=txt_testdesc]").val(),
                                txt_remarks       : $("input[name=txt_remarks]").val(),
                                txt_exp_res       : $("input[name=txt_exp_res]").val(),
                                txt_exp_cha       : $("input[name=txt_exp_cha]").val(),
                                txt_testwebsite   : $("input[name=txt_testwebsite]").val()
                            },
                            success: function(data){ 
                            if(data.response=="successful"){
                                alert('Save Successful.');
                                window.location.assign("<?php echo site_url();?>/testscript/testscript");
                            }else{
                                alert('error');
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
```

my problem is after saving, the whole form initializes. I should be able to keep the values inside the div and initialize only the text fields. I hope someone can help me... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are refreshing the page, obviously when you are refreshing the page it will not contain the values any more,try not to refresh the page on ajax complete on complete if you want to do something please use .html() .text() .val() this methods

Comment: i tried removing the window.location.assign("<?php echo site_url();?>/testscript/testscript"); but it just retains all the values in the form... I just need to keep the values inside the div and initialize only the textfields.

Comment: if you want to show data after the page refresh try saving them in session in the ajax page and check if the session exists and on success print them